# How To set up card information in cyber source for recurring payment

Tags: c#, .net, cybersource

I have a requirement to set up credit card for recurring payment in cyber source payment gate way .Also I need to get back the last 4 digit for card no and card type while authorizing the card in cyber source.
Does anyone know how this can be achieved using .NET Client SDK for the CyberSource.

Comment: Connecting to CyberSource and implementing any type of payment transaction is very involved.  The question seems to be asking how to do all of it instead of just having a problem with a small part.  Have you implemented any part of the solution?

Comment: Yes I did. In another application I am able to get flex key and post one time payment. Now we have requirement for recurring payment as well as store some card info while authorizing card . so need to know how that is possible

Comment: Documentation from CyberSource to perform recurring payments can be found here. https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/CC_Svcs_SO_API/Credit_Cards_SO_API.pdf  page 175.